# Javascript warning unreachable code after return best practice

Tags: javascript

I looked through the other questions on the subject and nothing was specifically about my subject.

Is there any rule against using this type of code. I feel like in this case, using else if is useless because every if has a return statement.

```
var __sortBySortType = function(x, y, index, type) {
    if (type === "name") {
        x[0]["sortname"] = x[0]["sortname"] || x[0]["name"];
        y[0]["sortname"] = y[0]["sortname"] || y[0]["name"];
        type = "sortname";
    }
    if (typeof global !== "undefined" && typeof global.locale !== "undefined" && global.locale.compareString !== "undefined" && index === 0) {
        return sim.locale.compareString(x[index][type], y[index][type]);
    }
    if (x[index][type] > y[index][type]) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (x[index][type] < y[index][type]) {
        return -1;
    }
    //If sorting by grades return sorting by whatever is diplayed (name, login or id)
    return (index === 0)? 0 : __sortBySortType(x, y, 0, this.displayType);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "Best" infers some evaluation with alternative approaches. Without criteria for evaluation, "best" is simply opinion.

Comment: There is no difference between an 'if' and 'else if' here (it is a stylistic choice only), due to every branch being terminated. That being said, switching to the ternary at the end "looks ugly" to me, regardless of the other structure choices.

Comment: I know my code works, and would work exactly the same if I use else if. But I was wondering if there is a best practice rule that is set, because I like to follow guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have a return for each if statement, there shouldn't be a difference. It is best practice to do if-elseif-else though for future maintainability. I find it easier to read at a glance to know that it's all related as one block of options.

Comment: Do you have any link for documentation which details your comment please. Thanks !